# Using Java Swing, how could one implement a search box that has options similar to web browsers or iTunes?

Tags: java, swing, search, jcombobox

Didn't know quite how to title this question, so suggested edits are welcome.

Right now, I have a fairly simple pair of JComboBoxes for searching row & column headers in a heatmap display.  It's been augmented with the ability to allow wildcards.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: Current Row Search Implementation]

It works well enough, but a new requirement for the next version is to consolidate the pair of search boxes into 1 search box plus a few other enhancements.  Basically, what we'd like to do is enter a search term and have the resulting dropdown have 2 sections: 1 for options and another for the matching results.  The desired options would be things like this:

1. Search rows/columns checkboxes
2. song/artist/genre checkboxes (to use the iTunes analogy) or google/bing (to use the browser analogy)
3. Search within previous search results: like have a previous search term with an 'x' next to it to clear it.  It would act like a filter.

The thing about this is, the desire to consolidate 2 search boxes to 1 is to simplify the interface, but at the same time, we want this additional functionality.

A JComboBox doesn't seem to be able to handle something like this, and my search for alternatives isn't yielding anything.  I know this question is somewhat of a broad design question, perhaps not appropriate for stack exchange.  I'm still fairly new to Java, so any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE: One of the commenters asked for something more specific and pointed out the existence of different types of iTunes searches based on context, which I'd like to disambiguate.  Taking a look at how iTunes does it, I decided to try to mock up a graphic of what I was thinking I could do:

[image: mock-up idea for search options & filters]

So given this specific example, I envision separating the combo box and the search options, perhaps with a JMenu revealed using a button made to look like iTunes' search options feature.

So my evolved questions are (based on the above mock-up):

1. Can JMenu do this or is there another type of button-initiated menu I should use?
2. Can menu selections trigger a re-population of the list the JComboBox provides or would that have bad side-effects?
3. How can I alleviate the confusion of having a drop-down on either side of the search field?

Comment: You overall requirement is rather complex, you'd need some kind of popup window which could then contain the structure of the search you want to so.  Depending on which version of iTunes your talking about, the search seems to work differently.  If you need to search across multiple properties, I'd recommend you start with the concept of something that is searchable, allowing you to add/remove "searchable" elements, each element would then have it's own UI representation, as a idea

Comment: Yes, this question seems overly broad.  It boils down to "How do I implement a search engine?"  You might want to reword you question so that you are asking something specific.

Comment: It is broad, you're right. Just not sure which way to go with it. And yes, it is a complex requirement, though it is one that has some basis in what's out there in popular apps today and we're just trying to mimic it to gain that depth of function merged with a simplistic/intuitive/clean design. I'm glad you brought up the iTunes search, because there's an aspect I neglected to mention: the search bubble has a separate magnifying glass dropdown for its options. Something like that could simplify things enough, though I don't think I'd be able to put it inside the combo box like iTunes does.